# How to test if the JAVA_HOME-variable is set correctly for Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables, startup

I'm currently setting up a Tomcat Server under Ubuntu 14.10.

in `${CATALINA_HOME}/RUNNING.txt` it says, that either `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` need to be set. I filled the file `${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh` with:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

since

```
sudo dpkg -L 'openjdk-7-jdk'
```

indicated that this is the place where my JDK is installed. To test the location, i also tried:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/some-none-existing-place
```

which gave **no error** when starting tomcat using `${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/startup.sh` (although the path does obviously not exist)

So, when is this variable used by Tomcat and how can I check if I set the correct path (for Tomcat)?

Comment: @Vihar This does not tell me, if tomcat is satisfied with the setting in the `setenv.sh`. Tomcat uses the variable, but does not throw an error, if the path is wrong.

Comment: @Vihar: that only tells you if `java` is in the `$PATH` not if `JAVA_HOME` is set (those are two different things). Just typing `java` can succeed without `JAVA_HOME` being set at all

Answer (score 4):

Type in terminal,

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

It will display JAVA_HOME variable path.

IF nothing appears then you can set it manually by,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

This will differ according to your JDK type & version

Edit: Also you just follow the below to ensure you set in tomcat configuration file.

Hit `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open terminal and run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/tomcat7
```

Find commented `JAVA_HOME`, uncomment and change the directory to your JDK environment. Restart now and check for the error.

Comment: I know how to set environment-variables. I only want to find out, if the value in my JAVA_HOME (I tried `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`) is the value that Tomcat expects. Even without setting the variable, the tomcat-server starts. But in the RUNNING.txt, it says the JAVA_HOME is required to be set.

Comment: @Edward:: I edited the answer. Try that and check if it works.

Comment: there is no `/etc/default/tomcat7`, since I installed tomcat to my `~/home/bin/apache-tomcat`.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt, type :

```
java -version
```

> java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM)
>
> SE Runtime Environment (build > 1.8.0_60-b27)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

```
javac -version
```

> javac 1.8.0_60

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60

Answer (score 0):

So, what is your problem:
a) Tomcat does not start, or
b) it starts, but you do not know what version of Java it is using?

1. Check that your `setenv.sh` file is readable. If it is not readable, it will be ignored.
2. If JRE_HOME variable is set then JAVA_HOME will be ignored.

   If neither one is set, then there are some defaults that are tried, including a call to `which java`. (The magic is in ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/setclasspath.sh).
3. The ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/version.sh script will print the versions of Tomcat and Java.

   Tomcat scripts print the actual value of JRE_HOME when Tomcat starts if you have a terminal. (`if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ];` block in catalina.sh).

   In recent versions of Tomcat a `org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener` can be configured in server.xml and will print the path to java and other settings.
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/listeners.html